# How to draw a hollow 1? (Unit step, Indicator fcn, etc..)

Tags: amsmath, mathbb

I am trying to write a hollow number 1 for my unit step function. Intuitively, since `\mathbb{R}` provides the nice symbol for real numbers, I would imagine `\mathbb{1}` do the same. However:

```latex
Since the input is $u(t) = \mathbb{1}(t)$, $U(s) = \frac{1}{s}$.
```

[image: Very very weird mathbb 1]

What should I use instead?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You could load the `dsfont` package and execute `\mathds{1}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, but dsfont somehow isn't preinstalled in overleaf. Ended up using mathbbol instead.

Comment: You wrote, "dsfont somehow isn't preinstalled in overleaf." Are you sure? `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{dsfont} \begin{document} $\mathds{1}$ \end{document}` compiles *just fine* on my Overleaf account.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Overleaf's [great, big list of LaTeX symbols](https://mirror2.sandyriver.net/pub/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) document, table 316. Apparently not all packages include hollow versions of numbers. Refer to this document for more styles.

```latex
\usepackage{mathbbol}

% ...

\mathbb{1}
```

Comment: `dsfont,.sty` and  `cmathbb.sty` are giving better supports